# Upgrade docker-compose version on windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to update the `docker-compose` version on windows 7.? I tried `docker-machine upgrade default`, but it does't seem to update the version of `docker` or `docker-compose`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Docker docs, to upgrade Docker Toolbox, download an re-run the Docker Toolbox installer. This will update docker and docker-compose versions.